# How to pass list of files to winrar/7z for archiving in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, 7zip, rar

Lets say I've a text file which contains paths to specific files e.g.

*myFiles.txt*

```
c:\users\%username%\desktop\file1.pdf
c:\users\%username%\desktop\junk.ppt
c:\users\%username%\desktop\image.jpg
c:\users\%username%\downloads\d1.dwg
d:\someFolder\random.exe
.
.
.
.
f:\folder2\code\myprog.cpp
```

How can I pass this list to `rar.exe` or `7z.exe` so that it can archive these files e.g.

```
rar.exe myarchive.rar myFiles.txt
Or
7z.exe myarchive.zip myFiles.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`7z.exe a -i@myFiles.txt myarchive.zip`

Comment: This places all files listed in myFiles.txt at the topmost (root) directory.  Trying to find a way to add them so that full path to [sub]folders are preserved.  (So that when extracted, all files are placed into their respective subfolder(s)). I already tested the "-i" switch as "-ir@myFiles.txt" and this does not do it.

Answer (score 0):

For 7Zip You can do the following; including "-spf" will preserve the full path prefixes:

```
7z a -spf -i@".\listAllChanges.lst" allChangedFiles.7z
```